# Is it possible to check any input, if it is matched with String Type in if condition to execue bunch of codes?

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement

Mainly I was working with a code. where I am trying to get an input from a user in String type to execute some actions. If the user don't input any type of value it will give another message to him.

I was finding if it is possible to check that input equal to any String type!
I was trying this!

```
    if (!(edt.getText().toString().equals("null"))) {

        txt.setText("Hello"+edt.getText().toString());
    }else{
        txt.setText("Wrong input");
    }
```

Comment: Please give more details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: you are checking on the literal strings "null", you probably wanna check on the empty string ""

Comment: What class is `edt` an instance of?

Comment: @Adriaan must be an `EditText`

Comment: Mainly i was trying to check a String value in a if statement, if it is a  String type to execute some codes.

edt was an EditText name

Currently it is solved Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
    txt.setText(getResponse(edt.getText().toString()));

// ...

private getResponse(String input) {
    if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
        return String.format("Hello %s", input);
    } else {
        return "Wrong input";
    }
}
```